# How to enable auto delete Spark logs generated by log4j RollingFileAppender for the terminated application

Tags: apache-spark, logging, log4j

I am new to log4j concepts, In my application i am using log4j's RollingFileAppender for log rotation. I Don't understand what appends to logs generated for already terminated application, will they be retained forever. Then is not an optimal solution right. Please suggest or give idea on it. Thanks for your help.